# Console table output -> csv file - Export-csv

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, user-profile

I'm listing all "User Profile Properties" in the console by "Displayname, name and Type" Is there a easy way to export the table output in console to a csv file?

This is probably a question that has been asked many times before but I can't manage to find a good way to do this.

Capture of the output in console.
[image]

Script

```
###############################################################################
# Export user profile properties to csv
###############################################################################

. .\Environment.ps1


Write-Host "Retrieving User Profile Properties with $DomainUser at $FinalMySiteURL" -ForegroundColor Cyan

[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Office.Server");            
$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("$FinalMySiteURL");            
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;            
$site.Dispose();

Write-Host "Getting user profile manager ..." -NoNewline
Try
{       
     $upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);
     Write-Host "Done" -ForegroundColor Green
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    Write-Host "Error loading file, add $DomainUser as admin to the user profile service (admin/privillage)" -ForegroundColor Red
    Break
}

$userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("$DomainUser");


$userProfileProperties = $userProfile.Properties | sort DisplayName | FT DisplayName,Name,@{Label="Type";Expression={$_.CoreProperty.Type}}
$userProfileProperties


Write-Host "Export to output to csv file ..." -NoNewline
Try
{       
     $userProfileProperties | Export-Csv $scriptPath\UserProfileProperties.csv
     Write-Host "Done" -ForegroundColor Green
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    Write-Host "Error loading file, add $DomainUser as admin to the user profile service (admin/privillage)" -ForegroundColor Red
    Break
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing Format Table (FT) to a Select statement...

so this:

```
$userProfileProperties = $userProfile.Properties | sort DisplayName | FT DisplayName,Name,@{Label="Type";Expression={$_.CoreProperty.Type}}
```

becomes:

```
$userProfileProperties = $userProfile.Properties | sort DisplayName | select DisplayName,Name,@{Label="Type";Expression={$_.CoreProperty.Type}}
```

Comment: This is the answer.  Plexus81, your problem is trying to reuse Format-Table output.  The Format-* commands in PowerShell are only to be used when you display output on screen.  If you try to pipe them somewhere else, like you are here, sending `$userProfileProperties | Export-CSV`, you'll get mangled output.